# Vuejs: import function from external script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal

I need to get some functions from external script inside a component. As i found out, the are two ways of adding external scripts like that (i.e. paypal smart button):

first is in the mounted hook

```
mounted() {
    let paypalBtn = document.createElement('script')
    paypalBtn.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=some_client_id')
    document.head.appendChild(paypalBtn)
  }
```

the second one in the "temlpate" section of the component

```
<script type="application/javascript" defer src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=some_client_id"></script>
```

The question is how should i, for instance, use paypal.Buttons().render('#element_id') from the external script? If i do so inside the mounted hook it will through "is not defined" as expected, so what is the import statement i`m missing out?

Comment: have you tried to add the script directly into your index.html?

Comment: @fabruex yep, but it is still "is not defined" in a mounted

Comment: even without the `defer` attribute?

Comment: @fabruex neither with nor without defer

Comment: the error you get is "paypal is not defined" or something else is not defined?

Comment: @fabruex 'paypal' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it somehow

You can **add** external script **into your index.html**(in my case before closing body tag) and then just **use** **window**.paypal.Buttons().render() or whatever function you need in mounted hook of your component. It is available in **window**.anyFuncName